# Type-safe curried function for extracting property from object in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to add typings for my `prop` function. It's curried (key first, object last).

I tried with a following approach: after partially applying it to some key, I try to restrict it to an object containing such a property.

I tried to implement it in a following way:

```js
const prop = (key: string) =>
  <K, T extends { [key: string]: K }>(obj: T): K =>
  obj[key]
```

Unfortunately, this approach deasn't seem to work. Here's a code I'd expect to fail (I also included all this code in [a Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgJxHGBeGAKA1gUwJ4BcM0CAlmAOYCUaAfAFAwwA8A0gDQwAqMOAHlBxgAJhBgBvGAG1chYlDKUAukVYwAvrQwgARgCsiXKqrqMYuvTPxL69UJFgUcUAGIgQaeEjgYA5ADN3Xyp6AHpQmABJXj44HGBYUlgoD38AQ1IAG04IcmAcGACgmGEQHAgwX1h+UmhzMBgoAAtaxrw4+idXdwxJIqCiABYAJg0QsIjm1vAC1oB3EAQscgoYNLF+OIScYU45gq7eBCQEO3A6iBAAWxwAOQBXK50cBCIwR+eETy63EF7CwIgXxEXxpHTAXxjWzhRotMQzGCtMAgWBzJppWDRTbxKCcED3KBwAltOIlMoVKowQ7kfwvBA7CaYJK+MS+e5gLDIuaVEL2C7XO4fF4AdSSTXxUAAgmBkVAMaRwN9nL9-v1gTARlCgA)):

```js
const getFoo = prop('foo')
getFoo({ fooo: 42 })
```

with an error message like

```js
Error: type '{ fooo: number }' is not assignable to '{ foo: number }'
```

However it's not the case (it fails silently).
I would also expect to infer the type of property in an object, so this code fails:

```js
const someNumber: number = prop('foo')({ 'foo': 'abc' })
```

with error like:

```js
Error: type 'string' is not assignable to 'number'.
```

and this is working as expected. However, if I omit the type annotation on `someNumber`, it doesn't get infered, so for:

```js
const someNumber = prop('foo')({ 'foo': 'abc' })
```

type for `someNumber` is unknown.
Is there a way to satisfy all these constraints?

I've been also thinking to do so "the other way around", to give a type of the object we will be working on first, and then to do something with `<T, K extends keyof T>`, but this would force the user to provide type parameter each time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to develop solution using `mapped types`:

```js
const prop = <K extends string>(key: K) =>
  <T extends { [k in K]: T[K] }>(obj: T): T[K] =>
  obj[key];
```

Link to [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgJxHGBeGAeA0jApgDylzABMIZoEBLMAcwD4AKAa1wE8AuGLASjXoBQMTABU8hYmRgBvGAG1mMGtwC6XEXKwqYAXyYgARgCt1PdZu2pBww0YXsVAbgEDQkWLVxQAYiBBp4JDhGACIAMz8QnmcAehiYbwBDKgAbCAAaChpgXBgAcgiQPJgSEFwIMDzYAipoGHAYKAALWsa2OFwBTx8-RllCkC4AFgAmXWiXOJgAdVzuvAQkBBhGAzYlMDDcajoYBHKAVxTYKHbcHldwOogQAFtcADkD24NtrjBn1+X0bt8QPpghS4IUSBmAIXGzgEUwAgrRkmBMohkNsNlsdrQ9odjm0Opd3BQ7o9PttplRmiADlAYWAwCAoIkoFQGj8vH8AUCYKNIQIgA)

Comment: Well, `Record` is just a builtin alias for mapped types.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const prop = <Key extends string>(key: Key) =>
  <T extends Record<Key, any>>(obj: T): T[Key] =>
  obj[key];

const getFoo = prop('foo')
const result: string = getFoo({ foo: 42 })
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution works,but unfortunately it gives obscure error messages mentioning `Record`type (which may be very confusing for people non-familiar with this particular utility type). But actually your solution helped me develop my own, which makes use of only plain objects. I'll post it in a minute.